# Replicating Model Behaviour accross TensorFlow 2.0 and PyTorch

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, resnet

I am converting what was a PyTorch model from the [SenseFi Paper](https://github.com/xyanchen/WiFi-CSI-Sensing-Benchmark/tree/main), given that I'm still a novice at TensorFlow models, I am trying to figure out why my tensorflow models performance is so much worse than the authors PyTorch model. I understand the model may not translate one to one, but the discrepancy doesn't make sense.

I have:

1. Used Similar weight initialization
2. Channel first configuration
3. Made sure to use `tf.function` decorator.

I used the `_make_layer` function to build the model, I would appreciate any help in furthering my understanding.

My Model:

```
class Bottleneck(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    expansion = 4

    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels, i_downsample=None, stride=1, **kwargs):
        super(Bottleneck, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.conv1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(
                                            out_channels, kernel_size=1, strides=1, padding='valid',
                                            data_format='channels_first', use_bias=False,
                                            kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.he_normal(),
                                            bias_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.Zeros()
                                            )

        self.batch_norm1 = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(axis=1)

        self.conv2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(
                                            out_channels, kernel_size=3, strides=stride, padding='same',
                                            data_format='channels_first', use_bias=False,
                                            kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.he_normal(),
                                            bias_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.Zeros()
                                            )

        self.batch_norm2 = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(axis=1)

        self.conv3 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(
                                            out_channels * self.expansion, kernel_size=1, strides=1,
                                            padding='valid', data_format='channels_first', use_bias=False,
                                            kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.he_normal(),
                                            bias_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.Zeros()
                                            )
        self.batch_norm3 = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(axis=1)

        self.i_downsample = i_downsample
        self.stride = stride
        self.relu = tf.keras.layers.ReLU()

    @tf.function
    def call(self, x):
        identity = tf.identity(x)

        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = self.batch_norm1(x)
        x = self.relu(x)

        x = self.conv2(x)
        x = self.batch_norm2(x)
        x = self.relu(x)

        x = self.conv3(x)
        x = self.batch_norm3(x)

        if self.i_downsample is not None:
            identity = self.i_downsample(identity)

        x += identity
        x = self.relu(x)

        return x

class UT_HAR_ResNet(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, ResBlock, layer_list, num_classes=7):
        super(UT_HAR_ResNet, self).__init__()

        self.reshape = tf.keras.Sequential([
            tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(
                                   3, 7, strides=(3, 1), data_format='channels_first',
                                   input_shape=(1, 250, 90),
                                   kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.he_normal(),
                                   bias_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.Zeros()
                                   ),  # Specifying input shape and data format
            tf.keras.layers.ReLU(),
            tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, data_format='channels_first'),
            tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(
                                   3, kernel_size=(10, 11), strides=1,
                                   data_format='channels_first',
                                   kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.he_normal(),
                                   bias_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.Zeros()
                                   ),
            tf.keras.layers.ReLU()
        ])



        self.in_channels = 64
        self.conv1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(
                                            64, 7, strides=2, padding='same',
                                            use_bias=False,
                                            kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.he_normal(),
                                            bias_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.Zeros()
                                            )
        self.batch_norm1 = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(axis=1)
        self.relu = tf.keras.layers.ReLU()
        self.max_pool = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(
                                                     3, strides=2, padding='same',
                                                     data_format='channels_first'
                                                     )

        self.layer1 = self._make_layer(ResBlock, layer_list[0], planes=64)
        self.layer2 = self._make_layer(ResBlock, layer_list[1], planes=128, stride=2)
        self.layer3 = self._make_layer(ResBlock, layer_list[2], planes=256, stride=2)
        self.layer4 = self._make_layer(ResBlock, layer_list[3], planes=512, stride=2)

        self.avgpool = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D(data_format='channels_first')
        self.fc = tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_classes)



    @tf.function
    def _make_layer(self, ResBlock, blocks, planes, stride=1):
        ii_downsample = None
        layers = []

        if stride != 1 or self.in_channels != planes * ResBlock.expansion:
            ii_downsample = tf.keras.Sequential([
                tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(planes * ResBlock.expansion, 1, strides=stride, use_bias=False, data_format='channels_first'),
                tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(axis=1)
            ])

        layers.append(ResBlock(self.in_channels, planes, i_downsample=ii_downsample, stride=stride))
        self.in_channels = planes * ResBlock.expansion

        for _ in range(blocks - 1):
            layers.append(ResBlock(self.in_channels, planes))

        return tf.keras.Sequential(layers)

    @tf.function
    def call(self, inputs, training=False, mask=None):
        x = self.reshape(inputs)
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = self.batch_norm1(x)
        x = self.relu(x)
        x = self.max_pool(x)
        
        x = self.layer1(x)
        x = self.layer2(x)
        x = self.layer3(x)
        x = self.layer4(x)
        
        x = self.avgpool(x)
        x = self.fc(x)
        
        return x


def UT_HAR_ResNet50():
    return tf.keras.Sequential(UT_HAR_ResNet(Bottleneck, [3, 4, 6, 3]))
```

Training, and data loading:

```
def load_data_model(root = r'Data/UT_HAR'):
  data = UT_HAR_dataset(root)
  X_train = data['X_train']
  y_train = data['y_train']
  X_val_test = np.concatenate((data['X_val'], data['X_test']), axis=0)
  y_val_test = np.concatenate((data['y_val'], data['y_test']), axis=0)

  # Create TensorFlow Datasets
  train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_train, y_train))
  test_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_val_test, y_val_test))

  # Shuffle and batch the training data

  num_samples = len(X_train)
  batch_size_train = 64
  batch_size_test = 256
  train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=num_samples).batch(batch_size_train)

  # Batch the testing data (no need to shuffle for testing)
  test_dataset = test_dataset.batch(batch_size_test)

  # Optional: Prefetch and parallelize data loading for better performance
  train_dataset = train_dataset.prefetch(buffer_size=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
      test_dataset = test_dataset.prefetch(buffer_size=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
    
      # Optional: Repeat the training dataset for multiple epochs
      num_epochs = 5
      repeat_epochs = 2
      train_dataset = train_dataset.repeat(repeat_epochs)
    
      model = UT_HAR_ResNet50()
      return train_dataset, test_dataset, model, num_epochs

@tf.function(reduce_retracing=True)
def train(model, train_dataset, num_epochs, learning_rate, device):
    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate)
    loss_fn = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)

    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        epoch_loss = 0.0
        epoch_accuracy = 0.0

        for data in train_dataset:
            inputs, labels = data

            # Move inputs and labels to the specified device
            inputs = tf.convert_to_tensor(inputs, dtype=tf.float32)
            labels = tf.cast(labels, dtype = tf.int32)
            with tf.device(device):
                with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
                    logits = model(inputs, training=True)
                    loss = loss_fn(labels, logits)

                grads = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
                optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_variables))

            epoch_loss += loss.numpy() * inputs.shape[0]
            predicted_labels = tf.argmax(logits, axis=1, output_type=tf.int32)
            epoch_accuracy += tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(tf.equal(predicted_labels, labels), tf.float32)).numpy()

        epoch_loss /= len(train_dataset)
        epoch_accuracy /= len(train_dataset)
        print('Epoch:{}, Accuracy:{:.4f}, Loss:{:.9f}'.format(epoch + 1, epoch_accuracy, epoch_loss))


@tf.function(reduce_retracing=True)
def test(model, test_dataset, device):
    loss_fn = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
    test_accuracy = tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()

    for data in test_dataset:
        inputs, labels = data
        # Move inputs and labels to the specified device
        inputs = tf.convert_to_tensor(inputs, dtype=tf.float32)
        labels = tf.cast(labels, dtype = tf.int32)

        logits = model(inputs, training=False)
        loss = loss_fn(labels, logits)
        test_accuracy.update_state(labels, logits)

    accuracy = test_accuracy.result().numpy()
    loss = loss.numpy()
    print("Validation accuracy:{:.4f}, Loss:{:.5f}".format(accuracy, loss))


def main():

    train_dataset, test_dataset, model, train_epoch = load_data_model()
    device = '/GPU:0' if tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU') else '/CPU:0'

    train(
        model=model,
        train_dataset=train_dataset,
        num_epochs=train_epoch,
        learning_rate=1e-3,
        device=device
    )

    model.save_weights('./checkpoints/my_checkpoint')
    model.save( 'UT_HAR_tf', save_format='tf')
    model.save( 'UT_HAR_tf.h5', save_format='h5')
    files.download('UT_HAR_tf.h5')
    !zip -r /checkpoints/ /checkpoints.zip
    files.download('checkpoints.zip')

    test(
        model=model,
        test_dataset=test_dataset,
        device=device
    )



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Authors Model:

```
class Bottleneck(nn.Module):
    expansion = 4
    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels, i_downsample=None, stride=1):
        super(Bottleneck, self).__init__()
        
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=1, stride=1, padding=0)
        self.batch_norm1 = nn.BatchNorm2d(out_channels)
        
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(out_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=3, stride=stride, padding=1)
        self.batch_norm2 = nn.BatchNorm2d(out_channels)
        
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(out_channels, out_channels*self.expansion, kernel_size=1, stride=1, padding=0)
        self.batch_norm3 = nn.BatchNorm2d(out_channels*self.expansion)
        
        self.i_downsample = i_downsample
        self.stride = stride
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
        
    def forward(self, x):
        identity = x.clone()
        x = self.relu(self.batch_norm1(self.conv1(x)))
        x = self.relu(self.batch_norm2(self.conv2(x)))
        x = self.conv3(x)
        x = self.batch_norm3(x)
        if self.i_downsample is not None:
            identity = self.i_downsample(identity)
        x+=identity
        x=self.relu(x)
        
        return x
        

class UT_HAR_ResNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, ResBlock, layer_list, num_classes=7):
        super(UT_HAR_ResNet, self).__init__()
        self.reshape = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(1,3,7,stride=(3,1)),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(2),
            nn.Conv2d(3,3,kernel_size=(10,11),stride=1),
            nn.ReLU()
        )
        self.in_channels = 64
        
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=7, stride=2, padding=3, bias=False)
        self.batch_norm1 = nn.BatchNorm2d(64)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
        self.max_pool = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size = 3, stride=2, padding=1)
        
        self.layer1 = self._make_layer(ResBlock, layer_list[0], planes=64)
        self.layer2 = self._make_layer(ResBlock, layer_list[1], planes=128, stride=2)
        self.layer3 = self._make_layer(ResBlock, layer_list[2], planes=256, stride=2)
        self.layer4 = self._make_layer(ResBlock, layer_list[3], planes=512, stride=2)
        
        self.avgpool = nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d((1,1))
        self.fc = nn.Linear(512*ResBlock.expansion, num_classes)
        
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.reshape(x)
        x = self.relu(self.batch_norm1(self.conv1(x)))
        x = self.max_pool(x)
        x = self.layer1(x)
        x = self.layer2(x)
        x = self.layer3(x)
        x = self.layer4(x)
        x = self.avgpool(x)
        x = x.reshape(x.shape[0], -1)
        x = self.fc(x)
        
        return x
        
    def _make_layer(self, ResBlock, blocks, planes, stride=1):
        ii_downsample = None
        layers = []
        
        if stride != 1 or self.in_channels != planes*ResBlock.expansion:
            ii_downsample = nn.Sequential(
                nn.Conv2d(self.in_channels, planes*ResBlock.expansion, kernel_size=1, stride=stride),
                nn.BatchNorm2d(planes*ResBlock.expansion)
            )
            
        layers.append(ResBlock(self.in_channels, planes, i_downsample=ii_downsample, stride=stride))
        self.in_channels = planes*ResBlock.expansion
        
        for i in range(blocks-1):
            layers.append(ResBlock(self.in_channels, planes))
            
        return nn.Sequential(*layers)


def UT_HAR_ResNet50():
    return UT_HAR_ResNet(Bottleneck, [3,4,6,3])
```

Comment: Save both model implementations and compare with `Netron`, if something in computation graph is broken, it probably can be seen.

Comment: @AlexeyBirukov thats a great idea, I'll update you once I do that.